# ios - tableview Accessory indicator not shown

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

in my tableview i use a background image for my cells (totally black image) and i also want to use accessory indicator in my cells. in cell's properties window i set AccessoryDisclosureIndicator

in my .m file i put these codes for tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    }

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text=[arrMagaza objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];


    NSString *distance=[arrDistance objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[distance stringByAppendingFormat:@" km"];

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}


- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tablecell.png"]];
   tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   tableView.separatorColor= [UIColor clearColor];
   cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

but the accessory indicator not shown on the view when i run the app.
what am i doing wrong? is the problem about background image that i use for my cells?

Comment: Please post the code to add that adds the image

Comment: How do you set background image of the cell? Your code is ok the problem I think is that you draw the image over the indicator. Remove the backgorund image just for testing. And you should not have clear color on backgorund color of the cell, this will end up in slow scrolling speed

Comment: thanks for advices i remove that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method is deprecated now, so no need to implement this method. Try removing everything else looks fine.

Comment: yes i remove that code and now it works but i have one more question: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator but in white color is it possible to change its color and how?

Comment: For using custom images set accessoryView for cell with and UIImageView and set custom image (White color DisclosureIndicator) to the image view.